# Error in passing data into struct

Tags: c

I'm getting an error on a struct call inside a function. In the code, I am converting two bytes of data into one 16-bit data and I want to store it into one of my struct variables. However, I am getting an error that I can't pinpoint. The compiler is telling me that the error is in the line `unsigned int fat.sector_size = combinedBytes;`. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The error that I'm getting is

```
main.c:62:19: error: expected â€˜=â€™, â€˜,â€™, â€˜;â€™, â€˜asmâ€™ or â€˜__attribute__â€™ before â€˜.â€™ token

main.c:62:19: error: expected expression before â€˜.â€™ token`
```

```
struct fileSystem_info{
    unsigned int sector_size; //Sector size
    int cluster_size_in_sectors; //Cluster size in sectors
    int entries_in_root_directory; //Number of entries in root directory
    int sectors_per_fat; //Sectors per file allocation table
    int reserved_sectors; //Number of reserved sectors on the disk
    int hidden_sectors; //Number of hidden sectors on the disk
    int sector_number_of_first_copy_of_fat; //Sector number of the first copy of the file allocation table
    int sector_number_of_first_sector_of_root_directory; //Sector number of the first sector of the root directory
    int sector_numner_of_first_sector_of_first_usable_data_cluster; //Sector number of the  first sector of the first usable data cluster
};

//Converts two 8 bit data to one 16 bit data
unsigned converter(unsigned mostSignificant_bit, unsigned leastSignificant_bit){
    uint16_t value = (uint16_t)(mostSignificant_bit << 8) | leastSignificant_bit;
    //return((mostSignificant_bit * 256) + leastSignificant_bit);
    return (value);
}

unsigned int sectorSize (){
    struct fileSystem_info fat;
    unsigned char first_byte = buffer[11];
    printf("%hhu \n", first_byte);
    unsigned char second_byte = buffer[12];
    printf("%hhu \n", second_byte);
    unsigned int combinedBytes = converter ((int)second_byte, (int)first_byte);
    unsigned int fat.sector_size = combinedBytes;
    return (combinedBytes);
}
```

Comment: WHICH error? Please be more specific...

Comment: Updated with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
unsigned int fat.sector_size = combinedBytes;
```

remove the type

```
fat.sector_size = combinedBytes;
```

(... and perhaps have a break ... ;-)

---

Refering the question on version-info in the comments below:

Do something like this:

```
#define VERSION_MAJOR (0)  /* \                                          */
#define VERSION_MINOR (1)  /* +--<-- adjust those for upcoming releases. */
#define VERSION_MICRO (42) /* /                                          */

struct fileSystem_info
{
  unsigned int version;
  unsigned int sector_size; //Sector size

  ...
```

When initialising an instance of `struct fileSystem_info`, do:

```
struct fileSystem_info fsi = {0};
fsi.version = (VERSION_MAJOR << 24) | (VERSION_MINOR << 16) | VERSION_MICRO};
```

Doing so allows you a maximum version number of `255.255.65535`.

As you always write `version` to disk you could later determine which version you wrote by reading the first `unsigned int version` from the structure an then in decide how to go on reading. This might be relevant in case the **structure** and how its content is to be interpreted following `version` changed during the different releases of your program.

Comment: Hi alk, thank you for all the help! I just want to get my assignment done because it's due tomorrow. Just a question, is it okay to have an unsigned int type inside the struct? Are there any limitations to this? Thanks!

Comment: No more limits then to a "stand-alone" definiton. Referring structs: Optional padding introduced by the compiler might be an issue if size matters.

Comment: What I mean is, would there be problems down the line (like common practices I should know) in using and unsigned int type inside the struct, or is it perfectly acceptable? Thanks!

Comment: By that you mean that in the future, I might need to use an unsigned long or something?

Comment: Using any type in a struct is perfectly alright from the language concept point of view. If it makes sense in the context of your assignment I have no clew. If you do ot know (yet) what "padding" means just forget my comment. Or read about it if your done with your assigment, tomorrow.

Comment: @user2989964: Looking closer at what you seem to be writing: If you want to store the `struct fileSystem_info` onto disk and want to be prepared to update this and have future versions of the software still being able to read elder, then introduce a member to this struct as first member providing version info.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please? I'm not quite getting what you're saying. And yes, you are right in your assumption that I will be updating the info throughout the program.

Answer (score 1):

An identifier cannot have `.`.

At

```
 unsigned int fat.sector_size = combinedBytes;
```

you are defining a new variable of `unsigned int` type, called `fat.sector_size` (which is an invalid identifier.

If you want to refer to the member `sector_size` of the `fat` variable, don't use the syntax for variable definition. Just write

```
fat.sector_size = combinedBytes;
```